# "Can't set headers after they are sent" Error (Even with "Return" Added)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm an amateur developer working on a case management system for a capstone project in school. I'm using node.js/express in the backend. Every time I try to execute the following function, which saves all the case data from a very long form, I get the error "can't set headers after they are sent to the client".

There are multiple conditional statements in the same function because the requirements for saving some of the data is dependent on the user's input.

I've read everything I could about the issue on forums here and most advise adding "return" statements to the responses being sent within the conditional statements. But I've done that, and I still get the same error. I even tried adding "res.end" within the conditional statements to make sure the code within the entire function runs seamlessly.

I know there is some key concept that I'm missing or do not understand well, so I'm hoping someone can enlighten me. Please help.

Thanks.

```
saveCaseData: (req, res) =>{

        let caseID = req.body.caseID;
        let clientID = req.body.clientID;

        let firstName = req.body.firstName;
        let lastName = req.body.lastName;

        //clientcase table
        let date_intake = req.body.date_intake;
        let referred_by = req.body.referred_by;
        let contactInitiation = req.body.contactInitiation; 
        let client_electronic_signature = req.body.client_electronic_signature;
        let contact_electronic_signature = req.body.contact_electronic_signature;
        let dcm_electronic_signature = req.body.dcm_electronic_signature;

        //client table
        let gender = req.body.gender;
        let race = req.body.race;
        let ethnicity = req.body.ethnicity;
        let marital_status = req.body.marital_status;

        let best_contact_time = req.body.best_contact_time;
        let alternate_phone = req.body.alternate_phone;
        let preferred_language = req.body.preferred_language;
        let literateEnglish = req.body.literateEnglish;
        let literate_preferredLanguage = req.body.literate_preferredLanguage;

        let doesNotSpeakEnglish = req.body.does_not; 

        let primary_phone = req.body.primary_phone; 
        let email = req.body.email; 

         //emergency_contact table
         let emergencyContactFName = req.body.emergencyContactFName;
         let emergencyContactLName = req.body.emergencyContactLName;
         let relationship_to_applicant = req.body.relationship_to_applicant;
         let proxy = req.body.proxy; 


         //Risks
        let risk1 = req.body.r1;
        let risk2 = req.body.r2;
        let risk3 = req.body.r3;
        let risk4 = req.body.r4;
        let risk5 = req.body.r5;

        let risk8 = req.body.r8;
        let risk9 = req.body.r9;
        let risk10 = req.body.r10;
        let risk11 = req.body.r11;
        let risk12 = req.body.r12;
        let risk13 = req.body.r13;
        let risk14 = req.body.r14;
        let risk15 = req.body.r15;
        let risk16 = req.body.r16;
        let risk17 = req.body.r17;
        let risk18 = req.body.r18;
        let risk19 = req.body.r19;
        let risk20 = req.body.r20;
        let risk21 = req.body.r21;
        let risk22 = req.body.r22;
        let risk23 = req.body.r23;
        let risk24 = req.body.r24;
        let risk25 = req.body.r25;
        let risk26 = req.body.r26;
        let risk27 = req.body.r27;


        //clientcase table

        let query1 = "UPDATE `clientcase` SET `date_intake`='"+date_intake+"', `referred_by`='" + referred_by + "', `contact_initiation`='"+contactInitiation+"', `client_electronic_signature`='" + client_electronic_signature + "', `contact_electronic_signature`='" + contact_electronic_signature + "', `dcm_electronic_signarture`='" + dcm_electronic_signature + "' WHERE `case_id`='"+caseID+"';";

        db.query(query1, (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            console.log("Case Query Success - clientcase data saved.");
            res.end(); 
        });


        //client table

        let clientQuery1 = "UPDATE `client` SET `gender`='"+gender+"', `race`='"+race+"', `ethnicity`='"+ethnicity+"',`marital_status`='"+marital_status+"', `best_contact_time`='"+best_contact_time+"', `alternate_phone`='"+alternate_phone+"', `preferred_lanugage`='"+preferred_language+"', `reads_writes_English`='"+literateEnglish+"', `reads_writes_preferred_language`='"+literate_preferredLanguage+"' WHERE `case_id`='"+caseID+"';";

        db.query(clientQuery1, (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            console.log("Client Query 1/3 Success - client data saved.");
            res.end();
        });

        if(doesNotSpeakEnglish){
            let clientQuery2 = "UPDATE `client` SET `speaks_English`='no' WHERE `case_id`='"+caseID+"';";
            db.query(clientQuery2, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Client Query 2/3 - No, client doesn't speak English saved.");
                res.end();
            });

        } else {
            let clientQuery3 = "UPDATE `client` SET `speaks_English`='yes' WHERE `case_id`='"+caseID+"';";
            db.query(clientQuery3, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Client Query 3/3 - Yes, client speaks English saved.");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        //emergency_contact table

        let contactQuery1 = "UPDATE `emergency_contact` SET `first_name`='"+emergencyContactFName+"', `last_name`='"+emergencyContactLName+"', `relationship_to_applicant`='"+relationship_to_applicant+"', `proxy`='"+proxy+"' WHERE `case_id`='"+caseID+"';";

        db.query(contactQuery1, (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            console.log("Emergency Contact Query Sucess - Case data saved");
            res.end();
        });

        //Assigning Priority Level and Saving to the DB

        if((risk15 && risk16) && (risk1 || risk2 || risk3 || risk4 || risk5 || risk8 || risk9 || risk10|| risk11 || risk12 || risk13 || risk14 || risk17 || risk18)){
            let priorityQuery = "UPDATE `clientcase` SET `priority_level` = 'P4' WHERE `clientcase`.`case_id` = '" + caseID +"' ";
            db.query(priorityQuery, (err, result, fields) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(500).send(err);
                        }
                        console.log("Priority-4 Level Updated");
                        res.end();
                    });
        }


       else if(risk1 || risk2 || risk3 || risk4 || risk5 || risk8 || risk9 || risk10|| risk11 || risk12 || risk13 || risk14 || risk15 || risk16 || risk17 || risk18){
            let priorityQuery = "UPDATE `clientcase` SET `priority_level` = 'P3' WHERE `clientcase`.`case_id` = '" + caseID +"' ";
            db.query(priorityQuery, (err, result, fields) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(500).send(err);
                        }
                        console.log("Priority-3 Level Updated");
                        res.end();
                    });
        }

        else if(risk23 || risk19 || risk20 || risk21 || risk22 || risk24 || risk25 || risk26 || risk27){
            let priorityQuery = "UPDATE `clientcase` SET `priority_level` = 'P2' WHERE `clientcase`.`case_id` = '" + caseID +"' ";
            db.query(priorityQuery, (err, result, fields) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(500).send(err);
                        }
                        console.log("Priority-2 Level Updated");
                        res.end();
                    });
        }

        else{
            let priorityQuery = "UPDATE `clientcase` SET `priority_level` = 'P1' WHERE `clientcase`.`case_id` = '" + caseID +"' ";
            db.query(priorityQuery, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Priority-1 Level Updated");
                res.end();
            });
        }

        //Save Risks to Case Record in the Database (consider switch)

        if (risk1) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '1')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 1 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk2) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '2')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 2 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk3) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '3')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 3 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk4) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '4')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 4 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk5) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '5')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 5 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk8) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '8')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 8 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk9) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '9')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 9 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk10) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '10')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 10 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk11){
            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '11')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 11 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk12) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '12')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 12 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk13) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '13')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 13 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk14) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '14')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 14 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk15) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '15')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 15 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk16) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '16')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 16 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk17) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '17')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 17 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk18) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '18')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 18 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk19) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '19')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 19 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk20) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '20')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 20 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk21) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '21')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 21 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk22) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '22')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 22 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk23) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '23')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 23 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk24) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '24')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 24 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk25) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '25')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 25 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk26) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '26')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 26 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

        if (risk27) {

            let query = "INSERT INTO `case_risk` (case_id, risk_id) VALUES ('" + caseID + "', '27')"; 

            db.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                console.log("Risk 27 added to case record");
                res.end();
            });

        }

       res.redirect("/dcm-home/recommendedPrograms/" + caseID + " ");

    },
```

Comment: I'd start by replacing all that duplicate code with a function. Use an array for the risk, not dozens of separate variables. Next you should look into using Promises and `async` / `await` to replace that callback hell.

Comment: thanks...will give it a shot.

Comment: Chris, the async/await worked. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Cool, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to hit `res.end()` in your code example. When it's running, it's hitting that method more than once, which triggers this error. You can only send/end once per request.

So for example, you `res.end()` after each of your first two queries. The first time you call `res.end()` it ends the response, so when you call it a second time in the next query you see this error.

Also, I'm not sure what `db` you're using, but it's possible that `db.query` is running asynchronously and so is not finished by the time you send your response. So, your response could be sent already but then `db.query` throws an error and an error response is sent but of course throws an error because your response was already sent. In this case, you may want to use some awaits to make sure your queries are done running before you send your response.

Using `await` syntax with your code's first query would look something like this:

```
try {
  let query1 = "UPDATE `clientcase` SET `date_intake`='"+date_intake+"', `referred_by`='" + referred_by + "', `contact_initiation`='"+contactInitiation+"', `client_electronic_signature`='" + client_electronic_signature + "', `contact_electronic_signature`='" + contact_electronic_signature + "', `dcm_electronic_signarture`='" + dcm_electronic_signature + "' WHERE `case_id`='"+caseID+"';";
  let result = await db.query(query1);
  console.log("Case Query Success - clientcase data saved.");
} catch ( err ) {
  return res.status(500).send(err);
}
```

So there would be no more callbacks, you would just wait for the query to finish and you put that code in a try-catch block so that if an error occurs you can handle it just like you were before. Note that this might make your code *slower* because you are waiting for each result before continuing on to the next query, but it still may be the best option right now.

Comment: Hey Ashley, thanks for the response. But I was getting the same error even without the res.end()

Comment: You are also making multiple `res.status.send()` calls with a final `res.redirect()` at the end - you can only call one of these (sends/ends/redirects) a single time, any other calls and you will receive that error.

Comment: so what do you suggest? breaking the function apart into smaller functions? I have a long form that the user should fill out and then on submit, all of the data needs to be saved into the DB...in the past, I've done multiple queries within a single line of code but since this one requires conditional statements, I can't.

Comment: For now I just suggest more debugging to see what the exact source is - if I were you I would comment out all `res.send` and `res.end` and leave the only one as the `res.redirect` at the end. Then, if it resolves the error then the source is what I suggested. If the error is still there, I would go to the line it says the error occurred on and do some more digging plus comment out the `redirect` as well.

Comment: Thanks, Ashley. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what `db` you're using, but it's possible that `db.query` is running asynchronously and so is not finished by the time you send your response. So, your response could be sent already but then `db.query` throws an error and an error response is sent but of course throws an error because your response was already sent. In this case, you may want to use some `await`s to make sure your queries are done running before you send your response. (Gonna add this to the answer)

Comment: Ok, and I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Then I'd say it is asynchronous and could also be the source of your issue if one of the queries are giving an error. If you try `await`ing your queries instead of using callbacks you can catch the error before the redirect and then you won't also be trying to send a second, error response.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but what would the "await" syntax for that look like? do you mind giving an example based on a piece of my code? I've been researching, but I'm unsure of how to implement.

Comment: Updated my answer, no need for apologies, we're all always learning :)

Comment: Ashley, thank you sooo much. I'll keep you posted on the result.

Comment: Got it to work after adding the async/await...had a few errors in my queries, which led to hitting the res.status(500).send(err) ...and consequently, the callback hell. The try/catch within the async function helped expose the errors I'd been missing. I also had to rearrange the order of the conditionals...for whatever reason, it didn't work unless I put the if/else statements towards the end. Thanks for your help. It's a large project and my brain's been hurting :).

Comment: I'm so glad! Congrats on solving it, and good luck on the rest of your dev career!